# Is there a way to continuously update a method in an Android application?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create an app where you can enter in a series of button presses as a password.  When you press the first button, a method would keep track of how much time has elapsed, and at 5 seconds, the button press data is stored.

```
    long recordingTime = 0;
    boolean isRecording = false;

    // start timer for total recording time
    if(!isRecording) {
        isRecording = true;
        recordingTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public void update() {
    long currentTime = 0;
    // get current time
    currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // check if timer is over 5 seconds
    if(currentTime - recordingTime >= 5000) {
        isRecording = false;

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Max password time reached.";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();

    }
}
```

Comment: are you looking for recursion?

Comment: you don't need to continuously update anything. You need to schedule a method to fire after 5 seconds

Comment: Would recursion work?  I don't think it would, or it would be inefficient.

Comment: How would I get a method to fire after 5 seconds?

Comment: Here's a modified example of what I think you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266625/auto-execute-message-every-5-seconds

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this, but here's a straight-forward way to get it done:

```
view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //store data here
            }
        }, 5000);
```

Comment: So how would I get the to run after a button has been pressed?  I want the timer to start only after a button has been pressed for the first time.

Comment: You could set a flag in your onClickListener to run this only once. Something like:  if(!hasFirstButtonBeenPressed) { /*then run code */ }